# Incremental Gradle Build in Azure Devops CI Hi

Tags: gradle, azure-devops

I am trying to understand how to setup an incremental build in Azure Devops using gradle as build tool.

So far, I have tried to run gradle with  `--build-cache` and I am caching the $GRADLE_HOME/caches directory. In my understanding that should include the build cache.

It's not working however. When I run the gradle build locally, with all build directories removed, gradle is going to be able to skip about 80% of the build time by skipping 70/200 tasks when using the build cache.

When I run the same config on azure devops, however, gradle does not skip a single task, and therefore takes rather long.

I am sure, I must be missing something - but what is it? a

Comment: I am having the exact same problem with Azure devops. The cache is found and downloaded, but none of the build steps are skipped with the cache. Did you find a solution for this? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure DevOps' Pipeline caching (cf. [answer by `@Doomsday`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76389802/13134095)) has a problem in this use case, which is noted in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching)'s *"Cache task: how it works"* section:

> Caches are immutable, meaning that once a cache is created, its contents cannot be changed.

This means that the pipeline cache containing your Gradle build cache is only populated with the first build (unless it expires after seven days of no activity or you change the cache key), i.e. it will become less helpful as your build tasks' inputs change from their value during the initial build (e.g. because the code base evolves).

Instead of Pipeline caching, you can use a [Remote HTTP build cache](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html#sec:build_cache_configure_remote), which can be easily set up from the [`gradle/build-cache-node` docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gradle/build-cache-node/). (This, however, needs to run outside of your pipeline, to be able to persist the build cache state.)

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem with this is that when we build cache in pipeline, the cache might be created in the agent that is running, and once the agent is cleaned the cache might get removed. For more adding "Cache@2" task and setting "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.gradle" as path for the GRADLE_USER_HOME worked.

**How does the "cache" task works?** 
Caching is added to a pipeline using the Cache task. This task works like any other task and is added to the steps section of a job.

When a cache step is encountered during a run, the task restores the cache based on the provided inputs. If no cache is found, the step completes and the next step in the job is run.

After all steps in the job have run and assuming a successful job status, a special "Post-job: Cache" step is automatically added and triggered for each "restore cache" step that wasn't skipped. This step is responsible for saving the cache.

**Sample code**

Here is how you can set the cache using gradle's build-in caching

```
variables:
  GRADLE_USER_HOME: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.gradle

steps:
- task: Cache@2
  inputs:
    key: 'gradle | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/build.gradle.kts' # Swap build.gradle.kts for build.gradle when using Groovy
    restoreKeys: |
      gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"
      gradle
    path: $(GRADLE_USER_HOME)
  displayName: Configure gradle caching

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    tasks: 'build'
    options: '--build-cache'
  displayName: Build

- script: |   
    # stop the Gradle daemon to ensure no files are left open (impacting the save cache operation later)
    ./gradlew --stop    
  displayName: Gradlew stop
```

**Main inputs for Cache@2 task:**

1. **Key:** should be set to the identifier for the cache you want to restore or save. Keys are composed of a combination of string values, file paths, or file patterns, where each segment is separated by a | character.
2. **path:** the path of the folder to cache. Can be an absolute or a relative path. Relative paths are resolved against $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). For me this task work when I set GRADLE_USER_HOME corresponding to Pipeline.Workspace is the local path on the agent running your pipeline where all directories are created
3. **restoreKeys:** can be used if one wants to query against multiple exact keys or key prefixes. This is used to fall back to another key in the case that a key doesn't yield a hit. A restore key will search for a key by prefix and yield the latest created cache entry as a result.

**Reference:**
There are different other ways mentioned in this document. But the above one worked for me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops